# Create PDF in angular 8 in Hebrew

Tags: angular, jspdf, hebrew, export-to-pdf, pdfmake

I want to export a PDF in hebrew language using pdfmake library. I have a html page which contains the some hebrew text.I have used canvas linrary for screenshot but I want only text pdf not an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this solution fits your needs, but you could make property holding the Hebrew text that you would like to display on the PDF. Then simply add that to the pdf (using jsPDF in this case) with `doc.text(this.someHebrewText, 20, 20)`

I made an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-banach-4rv2p) in a Vuejs codesandbox (because that is what I know hehe). Let me know if that would work for you.